# NETSUITE Rest Api - transactionline uniquekey and duplicate associations with multiple account acctnumbers

Tags: rest, netsuite, unique-key

Netsuite REST API issue.

When I do an sql query like this - (ac.acctnumber = 123456):

```
    {

 "q": "SELECT * FROM transaction t, transactionline tl , account ac WHERE t.id = tl.transaction and tl.uniquekey = 111222 and ac.acctnumber = 123456"

}
```

I get just one record (as expected)

but when I do this:

When I do an sql query like this - (ac.acctnumber > 123456): **(greater than)***

```
    {

  "q": "SELECT * FROM transaction t, transactionline tl , account ac WHERE t.id = tl.transaction and tl.uniquekey = 111222 and ac.acctnumber > 123456"

}
```

I get many records returned.

I assume that transactionline has uniquekey and this line would ONLY be associated with ONE account - not multiple.

Q: Is this Correct? Then why am I getting multiple accounts returned that are associated with this uniquekey?

Q: How can I set the sql rest api query to just get JUST ONE transactionline uniquekey associated to JUST ONE account?

Thanks Dave

Comment: I have had odd results in the search api (not the query api) when I use an incorrect operator. In this case `acctnumber` is alphanumeric and Netsuite may be choking on that.   I do realize that `>` is a  meaningful string comparison in PL/SQL but the result seems odd enough to grasp at straws.

Comment: Thank you for your input - bknights

Comment: Did you get this resolved? If so can you post your solution?